# Create new Quote using Apex class

Tags: apex, visualforce, quote

i want to crate a new quote from my own custom controller and visualforce page can any one help me doing the same. as i don't have idea how to do it.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Welcome to SFSE - This forum is for help you get around specific problems with code you have written. It is NOT a forum to ask people to write code for you. There are many developers / consulting services you can hire to do that for you.

Comment: Hi "crmevengelist", it may be easier for us to help you if we know why you don't have an idea how to do this. Are you new to visualforce or apex ? Have you never used the quote object before ? Are you not sure what fields or business requirements you have ? By explaining us your thought-process and context, we can do a better job helping you. You can still edit the question to share more details, doing so will help us help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take help from below:
controller :

```
public with sharing class QuoteController {

public Quote q {get;set;}
public string qName{ get; set;}


public QuoteController(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
    q = new Quote();
    q = (Quote)sc.getRecord();

   } 
public Pagereference saveQuote() {
q.name = qName;
      q.opportunityid = '0069000000OaWIM';     
    insert q;
    pagereference pageref = new pagereference('https://ap1.salesforce.com/'+q.id);
    pageref.setredirect(true);
    return pageref;

}    
}
```

vf page:

```
 <apex:sectionHeader title="Quote" subtitle="New Quote"/>
 <apex:form id="formId" >

  <apex:pageBlock id="pgBlock" title="Quote " >
   <apex:pageBlockButtons id="pgBlkBtn" >
    <apex:commandButton id="saveBtn" value="Save" action="{!saveQuote}"  />
    <apex:commandButton id="cnclBtn" value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" />
   </apex:pageBlockButtons>
   <apex:pageBlockSection id="pgBlkSection1" title="Quote Information" columns="2">
    <apex:pageBlockSectionitem >
     <apex:outputLabel value="Quote Name" />
     <apex:inputtext value="{!qName}" />
    </apex:pageBlockSectionitem>


    </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: a lot of thanks to u. code works and i have finished my assignment.One thing remains is  i want to generate quotation pdf according to my own template i mean i am creating new customized template but it is not giving me facility to arrange the field and decorate page according to my own format.so, is there any idea about that.

Comment: sorry but i dont know about that mate.

Answer (score 2):

An option which I think you'll find quite helpful for you needs is to install the unmanaged package version of [Custom Quote Sync](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003Iop5EAClistingId=a0N30000003Iop5EAC) from the App Exchange. It has a Quote controller that you can always clone and customize to suit your specific needs. It comes with a VisualForce PDF template which can also be cloned and customized. I and others I know, use it all the time with clients as a basis for creating customized PDF Quote generators that sync with Opportunity.

There's also another unmanaged package called [Simple Quote v1.0](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000017lEqEAI) which allows you to generate a quote instantly as a pdf and send it via email in 2 clicks. You can easily customize the template to use it for orders or invoices. Either of these should suit your needs.